# Unable to set background image of Qframe using python

Tags: python, pyqt4, qgis

This question may be repeat but i am not get ans for my problem 
I am using python 2.7
Unable to set background image of Qframe using python following code works fine in centos but in  window 7 not even its did not show any error,

```
self.frame_2.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("border:0px;background-image:   
url("+self.getImagePath("4.jpg")+")"))

 def getImagePath(self,image):

    pluginPath = (os.path.dirname(__file__))
    themePath = str("icons")  + QDir.separator() + str(image)
    filePath =  pluginPath + QDir.separator() + themePath
    if QFile.exists(pluginPath + QDir.separator() + themePath):

         return filePath
    else:
        return ""
```

Answer (score 0):

This code work on windows.

```
import re

self.frame_2.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("border:0px;background-image:   
url("+self.getImagePath("4.jpg")+")"))

def getImagePath(self,image):
    pluginPath = (os.path.dirname(__file__))
    themePath = str("images")  + QDir.separator() + str(image)
    filePath =  pluginPath + QDir.separator() + themePath
    if QFile.exists(os.path.normpath(filePath)):
         return re.sub("\\\\","//",(os.path.normpath(filePath)))
    else:
        return ""
```

Comment: my code is fine for centos but it does not work for windows.